# apt-get install apache2-utils tries to install a non-existing package

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get, apachebench, apache-utils

when trying to install ab (apache benchmark) like this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

on my Mint 16 / Ubuntu 13 system I get this messages:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
[sudo] password for <user>: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-cropper libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libphp-phpmailer libphp-snoopy tinymce
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 82,4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 344 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apache2-utils
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main apache2-utils amd64 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main apache2-utils amd64 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

doesn't change anything, while this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils --fix-missing
```

changed the last line ofe the messages:

```
...
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

'ordering was unable to handle the media swap' - I see

When browsing the http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/ directory, I can see that there are numerous packages, but the 2.4.6 is missing:

```
...
apache2-utils_2.2.22-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 13-Feb-2012 02:34   89K
apache2-utils_2.2.22-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  13-Feb-2012 02:34   87K
apache2-utils_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb    27-Jul-2015 17:43   82K
apache2-utils_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5_i386.deb 27-Jul-2015 17:44   82K
apache2-utils_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9_amd64.deb    14-Jan-2016 18:15   80K
...
```

So, the questions are:

- why does the installer tries to install the non-existing package 2.4.6?
- and - more important - how to fix this?
- -> can I use a specific version?
- -> and what version is recommended for my system?

System Version Infos:

```
$ cat /etc/linuxmint/info
RELEASE=16
CODENAME=petra
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 16 Petra"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_petra_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_petra_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 64-bit


$ inxi -S
System:    Host: rupert Kernel: 3.11.0-14-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Linux Mint 16 Petra

$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16
DISTRIB_CODENAME=petra
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 16 Petra"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10"
VERSION_ID="13.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Comment: I'm facing the very same problem right now, did you find a way?